# ng-show does not work correctly with ng-animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

When animate module is loaded then ng-show does not work. Default value for ng-show expression is false, but element is still shown and class ng-hide is missing. If i unload animate module, then it works fine.

```
<script>
var app=angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngCookies','infinite-scroll','ui.mask','ngAnimate']);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/? Full context of the situation  would help us greatly and should give a practical example of the problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem. ng-class does not work as well. not sure what the problem is. the strange thing is that if I don't load this template via $templateCache, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, it's probably a timing issue, but there is a workaround.
in short, there is some collision between a class defined in the "class" attribute with interpolation, and other directives on the same element trying to add another class. removing the `class="{{::item.customClass}}"` gets ng-class and ng-show directives to work fine.

I couldn't reproduce it on a plunker, probably because of the large amount of components involved. we use $templateCache service, ngAnimate module, and a directive that uses ng-repeat with dynamic class and ng-show (and more, which did not seem to affect the problem). Removing any of those mentioned had solved the issue.
there is one thing I didn't try and that's trying to detach the code from the `ui-view` hierarchy, perhaps the ui-router is a part of the problem.

Debugging showed that after the ng-class/ng-show's watch executes, the right class was added and it looked like this: `class="{{::item.customClass}} ng-hide"`, but at the end of the digest cycle it looked like this: `class="myCustomClass"`. I guess that is what happens in your code as well.

The way I handled this situation is by moving `item.customClass` to the ng-class like so: `ng-class=[{ ... other classes}, item.customClass]`

it's a workaround and not a real solution because:

1. it's probably a real issue inside Angular's code.
2. I don't know how to use bind once here, and it's important of course.

Comment: Thank you so much. I move everything from class to ng-class and it does really work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). It works with Angular and you can trigger it by class='ng-show'.

Like this:

```
<div class="animated fadeInRight" data-ng-class="loginShow">
```

If you set $scope.loginShow to 'ng-show' in your controller it will trigger the animate effect automatically.

If you want to trigger the animate effect on 'ng-hide' you have to write it in your controller like this:

```
$scope.loginShow = 'ng-hide-add animated fadeOutRight';
```

Hope this helps!